# How to handle the recording issues in jmeter? (i.e) Smack plugin activities are not recording in JMeter

Tags: performance, xmpp, jmeter, chat, smack

I am trying to make a performance testing by using the JMeter for the User registration process in Chat application,which is developed by using openfire and XMPP. I am providing the different user details through CSV Data set.The issue i am facing is, The newly provided user details are not getting to save in the XMPP. As per discussion with the developers, They are using SMACK plugin(.jar files inside the programs) for the registration and other process.(i.e) The Jmeter is recording only for the API calls,Not recording the smack plugin activities due to this i am struggling to make the performance testing for the new user registration process in the chat application.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JMeter Test Script Recorder can only record HTTP traffic through proxy so if you configured proxy for smack plugin then recording cannot happen due to protocol not being understood.

Otherwise it's proxy misconfiguration.